# Get name of next Scene in build settings in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, what I want to do seems like it should be extraordinarily simple. I need to grab the *name* (not load it) of the next scene, as listed in the build settings.

I thought I had a simple solution by doing something like this:

```
int currentIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
string nextSceneName = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(currentIndex + 1).name
```

But apparently that "GetSceneAt" doesn't apply to the scenes in the build settings, instead it's for some kind of internal list that the SceneManager has.

All my google searches bring up solutions based on a specific naming order for your scenes, or exporting the list of scenes to a file before building (a list that manually needs to be exported), etc. I can't imagine such a simple problem requires such a complex solution, which is why I'm asking for myself.

How can I just grab the name of the next scene in the build settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Unity 5.5 this should work, if you are on an earlier version see below.

The most straightforward approach most people would try first is to use [`SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(buildIndex)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html) because it returns a `Scene` object with a name property.

However... the documentation for it mentions:

> This method will return a valid Scene if a scene has been added to the build settings at the given build index AND the scene is loaded. If it has not been loaded yet the SceneManager cannot return a valid Scene.

But all is not lost because there is also [`SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(buildIndex)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex.html) which doesn't depend on the scene being already loaded. It returns a project relative path to the scene which we can extract a scene-name from.

```
public static class SceneUtilityEx
{
    public static string GetNextSceneName()
    {
        var nextSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;

        if (nextSceneIndex < SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings)
        {
            return GetSceneNameByBuildIndex(nextSceneIndex);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetSceneNameByBuildIndex(int buildIndex)
    {
        return GetSceneNameFromScenePath(SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(buildIndex));
    }

    private static string GetSceneNameFromScenePath(string scenePath)
    {
        // Unity's asset paths always use '/' as a path separator
        var sceneNameStart = scenePath.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
        var sceneNameEnd = scenePath.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        var sceneNameLength = sceneNameEnd - sceneNameStart;
        return scenePath.Substring(sceneNameStart, sceneNameLength);
    }
}
```

Edit: The section below is included for historical reasons, it is only applicable to Unity 5.4 and some earlier versions.

Yes, unfortunately you are right, but...You're in luck!

I created a plugin/asset for that after reading your question, it's three small scripts and it should 'just work' and using it is literally just one line of code:

```
var buildSceneRecords = BuildScenes.Records;
```

The records contain the name, path and index for the scenes in the editor build settings.

You can get it here: https://github.com/sindrijo/unity3d-runtime-buildscenes

Comment: I was sick at home and bored.

Comment: @Andrio The new 5.5 version of Unity has added this functionality, I've updated my answer to mention it.